# Drop-down Selection Control - Windows 8 Metro - XAML

Tags: windows, xaml, drop-down-menu, controls, microsoft-metro

I want the dropdowns like in the pictures below:

[image]
[image]

I dont know how I get them. I suppose that these are some kind of comboboxes but I am not sure. Can anyone help me and provide the xaml code?! Thanks.

Comment: So what did you end up using/doing... ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suppose you are looking for **Combo box**: [Windows 8 store controls list (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465351.aspx) . To use:

```
    <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox1" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged" Width="100">
    <x:String>Item 1</x:String>
    <x:String>Item 2</x:String>
    <x:String>Item 3</x:String>
    </ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

you would have to use Popup. 
Below link might help you

http://rahulpnath.com/blog/windows-8-series-drop-down-button/

Answer (score 0):

These look like ListBoxes that were placed in some popups. Callisto has a [Menu](https://github.com/timheuer/callisto/blob/master/src/Callisto/Controls/Menu/Menu.cs) control that I haven't seen, but from the name of it - it might be similar (I think you are supposed to put it in a [Flyout](https://github.com/timheuer/callisto/blob/master/src/Callisto/Controls/Flyout/Flyout.cs) control).